# apply efect on div based on ajax response datetime field

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my first question so be kind :)

I want to apply a text effect like blink  on div id="UpdateLine1"   from 5/3/2021 3:41:**16** PM to 5/3/2021 3:41:**26** PM (means 10 seconds from event occured)
I get so far with google search ... now I am stuck ... date manipulation in js and apply style to div for a short period of time

Thanks

I have a txt generated from Microsoft sql database with a text and a date:

```
dbout.txt
text to show line 1|5/3/2021 3:41:16 PM
text to show line 2|5/3/2021 3:29:47 PM
text to show line 3|5/3/2021 11:14:52 AM
text to show line 4|26/2/2021 1:54:55 PM
event name         | date time when event occured
```

I read this text with a simple php code:

dbout.php

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('dbout.txt', true);
echo $file;
?>
```

I show this line of text in a html page (my code is a mess ....)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$.ajaxSetup ({
// Disable caching of AJAX responses */
cache: false
});

  function UpdateDB()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText.length>50 )
        {
    lines=xmlhttp.responseText.split('\n').join('<br/>');
    rnow = xmlhttp.responseText.split('\n');
    line1=rnow.slice()[0];
    line1=line1.split('|').slice()[0];
    line1date=line1.split('|').slice()[1]; 
        
    line2=rnow.slice()[1];
    line2=line2.split('|').slice()[0];
    document.getElementById("UpdateLine1").innerHTML=line1;
    document.getElementById("UpdateLine2").innerHTML=line2;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","dbout.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateDB();       
    }, 1000)
    }

    


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    UpdateDB();
</script>
<div style ="position:fixed;right:0;left:0;top:0;">
<div id="UpdateLine1" style ="background-color:red;text-align:center;paddding=0px;color:white;font-size:9.8vw;widith:100% "></div>
<div id="UpdateLine2" style ="background-color:blue;text-align:center;color:white;font-size:9.5vw;widith:95% ">...</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix several issues in your code.

- the date in the `txt` file is day/month; in JS you need month/day
- you were using `$` from jQuery but it wasn't imported anywhere; you were using `XMLHttpRequest` so there's no need for jQuery
- you don't need PHP to get the file
- be sure to add appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header; you can do this from `.htaccess` with

`<IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" </IfModule>`

Hope this helps:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function UpdateDB() {
                let seconds = 10;
                var xmlhttp;
                if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.responseText.length > 50 ) {
                            lines = xmlhttp.responseText.split('\n');
                            for ( i in lines ) {
                                let line = parseInt( i ) + 1;
                                if ( document.getElementById( `UpdateLine${line}` ) ) {
                                    document.getElementById( `UpdateLine${line}` ).innerHTML = lines[i].split( "|" )[0];
                                    let
                                        now = Date.now(),
                                        time = new Date(
                                            lines[i].split( "|" )[1].split( "/" )[1]
                                        +
                                            "/"
                                        +
                                            lines[i].split( "|" )[1].split( "/" )[0]
                                        +
                                            "/"
                                        +
                                            lines[i].split( "|" )[1].split( "/" ).slice( 2 ).join( "" )
                                        ).getTime()
                                    ;
                                    if ( now >= time && now <= time + seconds * 1000 ) {
                                        document.getElementById( `UpdateLine${line}` )
                                            .classList.add( "on" )
                                        ;
                                    } else {
                                        document.getElementById( `UpdateLine${line}` )
                                            .classList.remove( "on" )
                                        ;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open( "GET", "/dbout.txt", true );
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    setTimeout( () => {
                        UpdateDB();
                    }, 1000 )
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed;right:0;left:0;top:0;">
        <div id="UpdateLine1" style="background-color:pink;text-align:center;paddding=0px;color:white;font-size:9.8vw;width:100% "></div>
        <div id="UpdateLine2" style="background-color:yellow;text-align:center;color:white;font-size:9.5vw;width:95% ">...</div>
    </div>    
    <script>
        UpdateDB();
    </script>
    <style>
        .on {
            background: lime !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```